# Python: Adding multiple lines on a map between sets of coordinates

Tags: python, plotly, maps

I have the following code which works well:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode = "markers+lines",
        lon = [-74.164556, -73.214697],
        lat = [41.515941, 41.474395],
        marker = {'size': 10}))
    
fig.update_layout(
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
        'zoom': 1})

fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

I am now trying to add multiple lines from my dataframe but am not having any luck. This is what I am trying (have highlighted the new areas):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

Start_Lat = data['Start_Lat']  ## New code
Start_Lng = data['Start_Lng']  ## New code
End_Lat = data['End_Lat']  ## New code
End_Lng = data['End_Lng']  ## New code

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    mode = "markers+lines",
    lat = [Start_Lat, End_Lat],  ## New code
    lon = [Start_Lng, End_Lng],  ## New code
    marker = {'size': 10}))
    
fig.update_layout(
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'center': {'lon': 10, 'lat': 10},
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -20, 'lat': -20},
        'zoom': 1})

fig.show()
```

The data looks like this:

[image]

Is anybody able to tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors after running the new code? What's the output then?

Comment: well your issue is, the lat your providing is a tuple of 2 array but the input should be a single array....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data format, it's best to loop over the start and end coordinate pairs. Otherwise I think it should be a list with alternating start and end coordinates.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for row in data.itertuples():
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        mode = "markers+lines",
        lat = [row.Start_Lat, row.End_Lat],
        lon = [row.Start_Lng, row.End_Lng],
        marker = {'size': 10}))
    
fig.update_layout(
    margin ={'l':0,'t':0,'b':0,'r':0},
    mapbox = {
        'center': {'lon': data['Start_Lng'].mean(), 'lat': data['Start_Lat'].mean()},
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'zoom': 5.5})

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's cool how you use the mean long/lat to center things :)